# HTTP Status code 202 vs 200 for a POST request

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes, http-status-code-200

[image]

I have confusion that, Im using 202 status code, when I receive a POST request from a client (A) and B is processing it , passing the output to another endpoint(C).
In this case I use 202 status code when B receives the request from A.( I have added the sample message flow.)
B is not sending any other response back to A. So is that right using 202 or it should be 200 ?

My understanding is, we use 200 for GET calls, and for POST we use 202 if processing is pending.
Here i have pending the processing and i forward that output to C. Not to A.
So here is my confusion to use 202 or 200 is right?

### Edit

If it is a call back endpoint, (eg: in this picture B), would it be appropriate to have 200?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main purpose of using `202` instead of `200` is for a server to communicate to a client: "From what I can tell, the request looks good. However, we haven't fully dealt with your request yet and we aren't 100% certain it's going to succeed".

So if someone does a request, the server immediately responds and then forwards the request elsewhere, a 202 makes sense to me. If the request fails at the `C` endpoint, `A` it will be too late for `A` to find out about this.

If you respond with 200, it tells a client that the request fully succeeded.

Comment: Thank you..So I assume having 202 is appropriate in this case because, any errors occurs at 'C' will be handled by diffreent channels( emails etc...) But having 200 is, I assume will give totally wrong aspect..For a GET call 200OK with response would be appropriate, but for a POST like this case, 202 is appropriate. Correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: If it is a call back endpoint, (eg: in this picture B), would  it be appropriate to have 200?